# Show that $r′′(x) = −1$ for some value $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a smooth function $r : R → R$ for which $r(0) = r(1) − 2 =
r(2) − 2 = r(3) = r(4)$.
So based on my approach, we know that $r'(c)= \frac{(r(a)-r(b))}{(a-b)}$. and $r''(c)= \frac{(r'(a)-r'(b))}{(a-b)}$, however,I don't know how to obtain -1, could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Mean Value Theorem(MVT), we can find $a \in [1, 2]$ and $b \in [3, 4]$ such that $r'(a)=0=r'(b)$. Applying the MVT again we can find a $c \in (a, b)$ such that $r''(c)=0$.

Using MVT once again, we can find $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ and $\beta \in [2, 3]$ such that $r'(\alpha)=2$ and $r'(\beta)=-2$. Applying the MVT again we can find a $\gamma \in (\alpha, \beta)$ such that $r''(\gamma)=\frac{-4}{\beta - \alpha}$. Note that $1 < \beta - \alpha < 3$, so $\frac{-4}{\beta - \alpha} < \frac{-4}{3}$.

Finally, since $\frac{-4}{3} < -1 < 0$, by Darboux's Theorem(or by continuity of $r''$), there is some $x \in )\gamma, c($ such that $r''(x)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

In between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, there must be a $c_1$ such that $r'(c_1) = 0$.

In between $x = 2$ and $x = 3$, there must be a $c_2$ such that $r'(c_2) = -2$.

In between $x = 3$ and $x = 4$, there must be a $c_3$ such that $r'(c_3) = 0$.

So in between $x = 1$ and $x = 3$, there must be a $c$ such that $\frac{-2-0}{3-1}=-1 \ge r''(c)$. The upper bound happens if $c_1=1$ and $c_2 = 3$.

In between $x = 2$ and $x = 4$, there must be a $c$ such that $\frac{0-(-2)}{4-2}=1 \le r''(c)$.

Then you can use the mean value theorem to finish.